# What can we do to encourage new members to be more welcomed?

Tags: discussion

I feel like we have a reasonable supply of new members coming by, but they don't seem to stick around as much as we would like. What can we do to encourage these members to stick around for more than it takes to find an answer to a question or two?

Comment: Maybe you should put this on [chat] as well so that it gets more publicity.

Answer (score 2):

I think that it would help if we got to their questions faster so they didn't have to wait around. Also I think it would help if we lowered the 20 point requirement for Chat to maybe 5 points so that the newer users could join in the conversation quicker and then stimulated more conversation in Chat.